# Nginx reverse proxy configuration multi domains virtualhost

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, virtualhost

I'm having trouble configuring my nginx proxy despite reading a number of guides and trying for three consecutive evenings.

Here is my topology: 
[image]

(From internet) All traffic from port 80 is redirected to `192.168.1.4`, a ubuntu-server virtual running nginx.

I have a NAS which has a subdomain `myName.surname.com` which connects to the admin page. On that NAS, I have apache webserver running hosting a couple of sites on port 81, 82,

The NAS uses **virtualhosts**, so domains successfully redirect (without using nginx).

I also have an ASP.NET website running on IIS on another `192.168.1.3:9810`.

Now here is my NGINX configuration. I tried configuring it a few times but broke it so I've put it back to its default state:

```
server {        
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;      
    server_name localhost;
    location / {            
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1; #WORKS OK
    }
}
```

If I go on `myName.surname.com` or `wordpressWebsite.co.uk` or `myIISSiteDomain.co.uk` I am with config above greeted with the **correct page** at 192.168.1.1:8080 OR 192.168.1.1:81.

It's a start.

First problem is When I navigate to any other page (not home page) like wordpressWebsite.co.uk/blog, it breaks giving 404. So I have tried to differentiate between URLs? I read that the config should be something like:

```
server {        
    listen 80;
    server_name wordpressWebsite.co.uk;
    location / {            
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1:81;
    }
}
server {        
    listen 80;
    server_name myName.surname.com;
    location / {            
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1;
    }
}
server {        
    listen 80 myIISSiteDomain.co.uk
    location / {            
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.3:9810;
    }
}
```

But this is not quite right.

1) wordpressWebsite.co.uk loads up the page, but as soon as I go to any other link like wordpressWebsite.co.uk/blog it breaks, giving me my NAS error message like its trying to access 192.168.1.1/blog rather than the virtualhost ~/blog. It actually changes my URL in navbar to 192.168.1.1 so why is it behaving like this?

2) if I'm using virtual host, I don't think I should need to pass in the port via nginx for 192.168.1.1:81 (wordpressWebsite.co.uk). Surely I just need to point it to 192.168.1.1, and then virtualhost should detect that the url maps to 81? I'm not sure how to to do this as I don't fully understand what actually gets passed from nginx to the server?

Comment: Problem (1) sounds like wordpress needs to be configured with the correct HOME and SITEURL. See [this document](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`
See this https://www.geekytuts.net/linux/ultimate-nginx-configuration-for-wordpress/

Comment: closer, but now I'm getting an nginx error 500 when I go to domain/blog.

Comment: seem to be an issue with permalinks. I'm still having some problems but it's mostly working now, ty